# append tr when a value is not null using item template

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am appending rows using item template

```
<tr>
    <td>
         <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" NavigateUrl="bla" CssClass="display:inherit !important;" Text='<%# someFunction(School.Name,"Name") %>' runat="server" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

the problem with the above one is if `someFunction(School.Name,"Name")` returns `null` it appends empty `tr`, so i want to append tr only if `someFunction(School.Name,"Name")!=null`

So i tried the below code by adding a if condition but it is not compiling !!
It says school.name is not defined

```
<% if(someFunction(School.Name,"Name")!=null){
<tr>
    <td>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" NavigateUrl="bla" CssClass="display:inherit !important;" Text='<%# someFunction(School.Name,"Name") %>' runat="server" />
    </td>
</tr>                       
 } %>
```

Comment: somewhat unrelated.. `<%#` denotes the binding context.. `((MyClassType)Container.DataItem).MyPropertyName` is typically what I do (perform a cast)..to avoid possible reflection.

Comment: which control are you using, which has the ItemTemplate?

Answer (score 4):

You could take care of it from the code behind.

```
<td id="tdAppend" runat="server"> Content </td>


if(School.Name == null)
    tdAppend.Visible = false;
```

**UPDATED ANSWER**:

```
currentItemIndex = -1;
listView.ItemDataBound += listView_ItemDataBound;
CheckQueryString();

//Hide or show the table header based on id
HtmlControl thControl = listView.FindControl("thAppend") as HtmlControl;
if (thControl != null)
{
    if (obj.ID == 12)
    {
        thControl.Visible = true;

    }
    else
    {
        thControl.Visible = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < listView.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            HtmlControl tdControl = listView.Items[i].FindControl("tdSchoolName") as HtmlControl;
            if (tdControl != null)
            {
                tdControl.Visible = false;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

For convenience:

```
void listView_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {
        currentItemIndex++;

        ListViewDataItem dataitem = (ListViewDataItem)e.Item;

        HtmlTableRow trControl = (HtmlTableRow)e.Item.FindControl("MainTableRow");
        if (IsOdd(currentItemIndex))
            trControl.BgColor = "DarkGray";

    }
}

private bool IsOdd(int value)
{
    return value % 2 != 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew
it says tdAppend does not exist in the current context

the function is  a protected one and the file is a .ascx file

Comment: After adding id=tdAppend to the aspx, save it, compile. Then in the aspx.cs, type tdAppend and it should show up so long as you have runat=server in the tag. I will edit my post to show you what I mean

Comment: So you were able to get tdAppend in the code behind?

Comment: You might be able to pass in tdAppend to the function, as a parameter, and set it visible from the protected class based on null or not.

Comment: he would want it at the row level... and PageLoad occurs before OnBinding Events of the controls..

Comment: @BrettCaswell Yeah that is probably why i am not getting the tdAppend in code behind !!
not sure what the error is in the if block i have

Comment: that is not why your not getting tdAppend in code behind.. you aren't getting tdAppend because you probably added the runat=server attribute while in debug/run and it didn't add the control to your designer.cs file .. it doesn't really matter, as this is not a good solution anyway

Comment: Ok, so you are right @BrettCaswell, I had to find the control, but that was during page load.

Answer (score 0):

It's a pretty straight forward practice.. Handling the ListView.OnItemDataBinding event.

### Markup

```
<%@ Import Namespace="MyNamespace" %>

<asp:ListView ID="lview" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="lview_ItemDataBound" ItemPlaceholderID="Placeholder1">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td><%# ((School)Container.DataItem).Name %></td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table>
            <div id="Placeholder1" runat="server"></div>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

### Code-Behind

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
   public class Default : Page
   {
       IEnumerable<School> dataItems {get;set;}


       protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           dataItems = new School[] { new School() { Name = "School 1" }, new School() { Name = "School 2" }, new School() { Name = null }, new School() { Name = "School 3" } }.AsEnumerable();
           lview.DataSource = dataItems;
           lview.DataBind();
       }

       protected void lview_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
       {            
           ListView listview = (ListView)sender;
           ListViewItem row = e.Item;
           School dataItem = (School)e.Item.DataItem;

           if (dataItem.Name == null)
           {
               row.Visible = false;
           }

       }
   }
   public class School
   {
       public string Name { get; set; }
   }
}
```

---

personally, I don't usually use tables.. it's a fairly odd-looking layout template.